# Using Tailwind prose on dark background makes text look too dark

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

**Using Tailwind prose on dark background makes text look too dark without manual configuration**

**TLDR;** How do I get prose to work on a dark background?

I have a Site running Sage 10 with Wordpress, where I use TailwindCSS (v3.0.18) for the base styling.
The page is not in dark mode, nor should it be. However I have a Footer, that has a dark background, as is quite common with Websites.
My issue is that the `prose` class I add to it, will show the text (etc.) quite dark, not really readable. I want to have `prose` usable on dark backgrounds too. `prose-invert` doesn't seem to work. I am not sure if it only works with `dark:prose-invert`?

I could manually change all the elements within the footer, but I would prefer if Tailwind had a way of handling this witout manual labor.

In the image you can see the left part has `prose` and ends up dark. The right part does not and keeps looking as it should, but is missing the sizes and all the fancy stuff.

[image]

My `tailwind.conf.js` is setup very minimalistic at this point:

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    // WP default php files
    './index.php',
    './functions.php',
    './author.php',
    './archive.php',
    './home.php',
    './front-page.php',
    './404.php',
    './search.php',
    './category.php',
    './page.php',
    './single.php',
    './taxonomy.php',
    // END WP default php files
    './resources/views/**/*.php',
    './resources/scripts/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.indigo,
        secondary: colors.yellow,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

I compile everything with composer into one CSS file, so Tailwind JIT is in use and scans all the correct files as you can see.

Following is a very minimal example of the compiled HTML (removed a lot of stuff, just for demo purposes):

```html
<footer class="footer bg-stone-800 p-8">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="sm:flex gap-x-3 mb-4">                      
      <div class="prose-invert footer__item sm:w-1/4 h-auto">
        <section class="widget block-15 widget_block">
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </section>          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your HTML, where you are declaring the class `prose-invert`, you need to also use the base class of `prose`.

So ending up with at least `prose prose-invert` in your class list.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by adding two classes as outlined below:

```
class="prose dark:prose-invert"
```

The `prose` class ensures proper functionality in the browser's day mode. Meanwhile, when the user switches to or is already in dark mode, the `dark:prose-invert` class comes into play.

When you use the `dark:prose-invert` class, it takes care of how the text looks on dark backgrounds. You don't have to manually set it up, making things easier. This simple adjustment ensures that the text looks better and more consistent, providing a genuine improvement in how things appear visually.